# ElastichSearch Count Discrepancies

Tags: elasticsearch, count, sharding

I have an ElasticSearch (v7.4) cluster with 3 master nodes and 4 data nodes. When gathering statistics about the number of documents, I have come across a few apparent inconsistencies:

- The number of documents as returned by `GET https://<my_ip>/<my_index>/_count`: 66717419 (24 shards)
- The number of documents as returned by `GET https://<my_ip>/<my_idnex/_search?track_total_hits=true`: 66717419 (same as above)
- Now I checked the number of documents where the id starts with `0`:

```
curl 'https://<my_ip>/<my_index>/_search?track_total_hits=true' -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "id": {
        "value": "0"
      }
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true, "size": 0
}'
{"took":5,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":24,"successful":24,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":57565,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

- Repeating the same query for all of `[0-9a-f]` also returns numbers between 57k and 58k for each of these letters/digits for `hits.total.value` (just as shown in the example query for `0` above).
- Repeating the same query for any other letters returns 0 results (as expected).
- These totals sum up to ~912k total documents (16*57k)

So I see **~900k documents** that have an `id` starting with any of `[0-9a-f]`, 0 starting with other ids. At the same time, ES reports a total of **66M documents** in the index.
Where does the discrepancy come from? Can there be documents with no id? Does ES count deleted or updated documents somehow?

According to the [ID Field documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html)

> Each document has an _id that uniquely identifies it

Could it be related to sharding? From the results shown above, however, it looks like each of my queries hits all 24 shards.

The documentation for the [Count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) or the [Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) don't seem to indicate any peculiar behaviour in that regard. What else could explain these numbers?

**Update:**
The index statistics:

```
health status index            uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   <my_index> BUWfFDsBQAGcl64-J7gzHQ  24   1   66717419     23791236      1.6tb          873gb
```

Comment: 3 questions: 1) How you do generate the IDs of your documents? 2) Which version are you running? 3) What's the mapping of the `id` field?

Comment: 1) The IDs are generated in a custom function based on customer IDs and unique document provenance
2) ES version is 7.4
3) Mapping of `_id` is `type: keyword`

Comment: Are the IDs always in lowercase? or could you also have uppercase letters?

Comment: The IDs are always in lowercase. The custom function is based on built-in hash functions, and I have double-checked: there are no doc ids starting with `A`, `B` etc.

Comment: You mention `_id` but the field you're checking with is `id`, do they have the same value?

Comment: Also it should have no impact, but do you have nested documents?

Comment: Also can you share what you see when running `GET _cat/indices/<myindex>?v`

Comment: I _guess_ the `id` vs. `_id` is the key. I was indeed searching based on `id`. Searching on `_id` throws an error: `"Can only use prefix queries on keyword and text fields - not on [_id] which is of type [_id]"`

Comment: I've added the index stats to the question.

Comment: but `id` and `_id` contain the same value?

Comment: Yes, `_id` and `id` should be identical, and they are in all documents that I have seen.

Comment: Can you run this query `{"size":0,"aggs":{"ids":{"terms":{"script":"doc['id'].value.substring(0, 1)","size":"100","missing": "NOID"}}}}` and update your question with the results, please?

Comment: I've just run a `must_not` exists query for the `id` field, and there are ~65M docs without an `id`. I guess that explains the discrepancy.

Comment: Yes, that was the goal of the above query. But good you figured it out already

Comment: Thanks a lot! I suppose the answer is that there is a bug somewhere in my custom indexing logic.